# What are the minimum software specifications for Android 11

Tags: updates

What are the minimum software specifications for Android 11, what is the minimum specification needed for android 11 in terms of processor, screen, and other capabilities?

Comment: As Android is not an OS you can freely install, there are no easy requirements. Usually the manufacturer of each device decides if and how you can upgrade a device. For the other requirements see the [Android 11 Compatibility Definition](https://source.android.com/compatibility/11/android-11-cdd?hl=en)

Comment: Looks like what you are asking is about hardware specification (e.g. processor, screen), which is already asked and answered on the duplicate. Not sure what you mean by software requirement though. Could you [edit] to clarify that?